# How sleep mechanism works in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, timer, daemon, systemd

We have an embedded Linux in which we manage and control many* subsystems. In addition, it has a communication medium which allows us to communicate with it without a cable(S-Band). 
Currently, I am dealing with some scripts where we can use them during the operation period.

Here is a timer prototype, where we can activate some scripts when the clock shows 00:00.

```
while [ 1 ]; 
do
    curHour="$(date +%H)"
    curMin="$(date +%M)"
    echo $curHour:$curMin
    if ((10#$curHour=="0")); then 
        if((10#$curMin=="0"));then
            ./archAndComp.sh
        fi
    fi  
    sleep 60
done
```

The script I am calling has particular jobs which are archiving and compressing the desired directory. Here is the prototype of what I explained.

```
dirName="logs"
j=0
if (find $PWD $dirName*); then
    i=0
    while (find $PWD $dirName-$i.tar.xz);
    do
        let i++
    done
    tar -cvf $PWD/$dirName-$i.tar $PWD/var/log/$dirName 
    xz  $PWD/$dirName-$i.tar
else
    tar -cvf $PWD/$dirName-$j.tar $PWD/var/log/$dirName 
    xz  $PWD/$dirName-$j.tar
fi
```

In summary, at the end of every day I want to archive and compress a specific directory. The file transfer/download script is provided. Thus, no need to discuss that part.

The thing that bugs me is; when the timer.sh script is active, does it cause a process sleep which does not allow any other process to be completed? Alternatively, some internal scheduler may assign the `sleep` to a thread-like mechanism which allows other processes to continue their lives...

For the first case, I should daemonize the timer script. What would be your suggestions, should I stick with systemd or implement my own clock-like daemon?

Comment: Sleeping isn't usually a CPU intensive activity, and the scheduler will likely let other processes go unless you've got some strange setup.  That said, why not just use `cron` to run this every day?  Running stuff every so often is exactly what it's there for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eric Renouf has a point - unless you are really tight on memory on your embedded system, `cron` is a fine way to schedule running of other process on regular basis. However, if you decide to stuck with bash solution, there are some hints.

By custom `while true` is used for infinite loop. There are some technical details hidden causing it could be a little better than `while [1]`. A little better as in: you may spare literally a few CPU cycles. So, it's not very bothering.

You have choose quite elaborate way to check if the time to run a process arrived. It could be done simpler:

```
if [ "$(date +%H%M)" = "0000" ]; then
  ./do-something.sh
fi
```

There is no need to check the time every 60 seconds. You can check the current time and sleep until midnight:

```
while true; do
  t=( $(date +"%H %M %S") )   # store current hh:mm time into an array
  if [ "${t[0]}${t[1]}" = "0000" ]; then
    ./do_something.sh      # it could be a time consuming process
    t=( $(date +"%H %M") ) # so we want to know when it ends
  fi
  # sleep till next midnight
  sleep $[ 86400 - 3600 * ${t[0]} - 60 * ${t[1]} - ${t[2]} ] 
done
```

You may want to call your script in the background:

```
./my_scheduler.sh &
```

Also, you may want to keep the log from whatever you called from inside your scheduler:

```
./do_something.sh > /log/something.log 2>&1
```

And as for your original question: the sleep from bash is implemented using the [sleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) system call. More or less, it means for scheduler (a kernel subsystem deciding when to assign a CPU time for a process/thread): do not run me, unless the specified time pass or something special happen. Therefore, sleeping process does not eat CPU resource.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.